# Web API extending IdentityUser and custom queries

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my AccountController of Web API I have access to the UserManager, which provides methods like GetUserById().  I need to query the context and search for a list of users based on properties that I have extended - I need to add a 'GetUsersByPhoneNumber()' method, for example.

AppUser is my extended class, which inherits IdentityUser.

My constructors look like this.  Any example I find on the net shows something different with the context being passed in.  I cannot see where I can access the dbcontext..

```
    public AccountController()
        : this(Startup.UserManagerFactory(), Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat)
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
        ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }
```

How can I get access to the dbcontext and perform my own queries based on the extra fields I have added to the AppUser class?

Answer (score 0):

The UserManager is meant to be agnostic about the store, you can drop down and access things off of the DbContext itself if you hang onto the UserStore itself that the UserManager was constructed with.

Since a factory created your user manager, you might need to subclass UserManager to pubicily expose access to the IUserStore which is protected by default.  Once you have the store, you can cast it to UserStore and get at the DbContext directly.

Another possibly cleaner way to do the same thing would be to extend UserManager and expose a new GetUsersByPhoneNumber() from the UserManager itself since it already has access to everything you need